# how to give address of parts to copy command in c#

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

when i run copy command in my c# code it produce no error or exception because it is not finding the parts path i do not know how to give full directory path or path of every part which i am joining.actually i am merging file parts to a single file using coy/b by using this code...

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText = "/C copy/b test.txt.10485760.0000.part" + 
            "test.txt.10485760.0001.part" + 
            "test.txt.10485760.0002.part" + 
            "test.txt.10485760.0003.part" + 
            "test.txt.10485760.0004.part" + 
            "test.txt.10485760.0005.part test.txt";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Comment: Have you ever checked what the actual value of `strCmdText` is??

Comment: In particular, if you're trying to join the various `.part` files together, you need `+` actually _in_ the command ... each line except the last should end `...0000.part + " + `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the path of your files as the working path of the process. For example:

```
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
  WorkingDirectory = @"THE\PATH\OF\FILES",  
  WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
  FileName = "cmd.exe",
  Arguments = "YOUR COMAND HERE";
};
Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

For your command, note that you can copy all files into one using a wildcard for the parts:

```
copy *.part test.txt
```

/b is for binary data, so i think is not needed in your case.

You can also set other properties for a process, for more info check the doc: [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For such a complex task, I would use the process as a bash rather then just an execution tool.

1. Create a Process
2. Redirect it's streams [(Input, Output)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. With a `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` u can now access the cmd

Now just control it the way u need it, like setting the working directory to the path and do ur command.

If this is not what u want, u can allways set the working directory on the `ProcessStartInfor` -> [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)